# Azure Blob redirect

Tags: azure, http-status-code-404, blob, azure-blob-storage, http-redirect

We have an Azure Blob storage, and some folders on it were redirected to a custom URL.

Suddenly those custom urls coming up with 404 page

Files are still accessible from original location. So I guess something happened with redirect.

How do I check redirect for Azure blob containers?

Thank you!

Comment: What about the custom url? Could you show us?

Comment: This is a custom url tht's not working http://web.industracom.com/info/MS-Demographics.pdf

Comment: This is actual location https://appsindustracom.blob.core.windows.net/info/IS-Demographics.pdf

Comment: So did you mean you bind the blob endpoint url to your custom domain name like http://web.industracom.com?

Comment: Yes when I click web.industracom.com/info/MS-Demographics.pdf it should go to Azure blob container, but redirect doesn't work

Comment: Can you share how you have set up the redirection? Please edit your question and include these details there instead of providing them in comments.

Comment: Please check the URL is correct. There is no issue from your storage and that can be access.

Answer (score 1):

When you bind your blob endpoint url, I suggest you could check whether there is a space in text box. Because the 404 error means the url is not correct. And in your comment,it seems that you should use **IS-Demographics.pdf**  instead of 'MS' in domain name.

Besides, I have binded the domain name to blob endpoint url ,it works fine on my side. I suggest you could try the following steps to achieve your goal.

1. In App Service Domain>DNS Zone>click **Record set** button, you could bind your domain name to your blob endpoint url(like [storage account name].blob.core.windows.net).

[image]

2. In Storage account>Custom domain>enter your domain name and click Save button:
   [image]

Finally,if I visit a txt file in container by domain name, it works fine:

[image]

Visit txt file by blob endpoint url:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Always use without encoded blob URL while redirection.
Azure API always construct encoded blob URL. If your blob name contains Space character then after encode it converts to %20.
Some redirection function again encode this encoded URL and produce 404 error.